# syntax error near unexpected token `(' : output awk result as variable

Tags: bash, variables, awk

I want to process a tab-limited file text using awk and set the output as variable in unix.

I wanted to i) select lines that have unique combinations of values in the 1st and 3rd column; ii) sort by increasing numeric value at the first column; iii) extract the first column; etc..
So I used the following script:

```
locus_overmerged=$(awk -F"\t" '!seen[$1, $3]++' <(gzip -dc $id) | sort -n -k1,1 | cut -f1 | uniq -dc | awk '{print $2}')
```

If I run it by hand in the terminal, it works. However, when I input this command in a script, I obtain the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
` awk -F"\t" '!seen[$1, $3]++' <(gzip -dc $id) | sort -n -k1,1 | cut -f1 | uniq -dc | awk '{print $2}' )'
```

Any idea on what it could be the problem?

Comment: `<(...)` is bash-only syntax; this looks like you're running your script with `/bin/sh`. Check that it's actually being run with bash -- with a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, and **not** being invoked using `sh scriptname`.

Comment: yes, It is a #!/bin/sh script.

Comment: BTW, unrelated to the syntax error, but `gzip -dc <"$id"` or `gzip -dc -- "$id"` is going to be a bit more reliable; unquoted expansions have some undesirable side effects.

Comment: ...yup, can't use that syntax in `/bin/sh` (and questions about that language should be tagged `sh`, not `bash`).

Comment: Ok, you were right. I replaced /bin/sh with /bin/bash